# Difference between `xhr.onload = ()=>{resolve();}` and `xhr.onload = resolve();`

Tags: node.js, ajax, promise, xmlhttprequest

```js
function foo(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method,url);
      xhr.onload = ()=>{ resolve(xhr); };
      xhr.send();
   })
}
```

Code above works well

but

```js
function foo(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method,url);
      xhr.onload = resolve(xhr);
      xhr.send();
   })
}
```

But this code won't works.

As `onload()` is a event handler that setting a **function** for certain event
Its hard to understand the difference of both code above :(
Dose `resolve` inside the `new Promise` object is not a function?
Why does `xhr.onload = resolve();` doesn't work?

Comment: I answered assuming you did '...xhr.onload = resolve(xhr)'. Please correct the second codeblock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**xhr.onload = resolve()**

Here you're calling the resolve callback(notice the parenthesis), so you're basically doing:

xhr.onload = (value returned by the call to resolve(xhr).

when you need to provide a function to 'onclick'.
So here the promise resolves immediately as you are calling resolve. And doesn't work as expected.

**xhr.onload = () => {resolve(xhr)}**

Here you're providing a function(which calls resolve inside), so it works.

Comment: please correct your question, as per my comment above. Thanks. And no problem :)